# Change text of first child

Tags: javascript

I have code that suppose to find the first child (div) of a div and than change its content, here is my code:

```
var headDiv = document.getElementById('sliderContainer');
var childDiv = headDiv.childNodes[0];
childDiv.innerHTML = 'Working';
```

that seems to not working, what's the problem here?

live : http://jsbin.com/aqozef/edit#javascript,html,live

the full code :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="javascript">
        function scrollit(){
            var headDiv = document.getElementById('sliderContainer');
            var childDiv = headDiv.childNodes[0];
            childDiv.innerHTML = 'Working';
        }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #sliderContainer{width:100px;height:100px;overflow:hidden;}
        .sliderContent{width:100px;height:100px;float:left;}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="sliderContainer">
        <div class="sliderContent" style="background-color:blue;">s</div>
        <div class="sliderContent" style="background-color:yellow;">a</div>
    </div><br/><br/>
    <button onclick="scrollit();">scroll it</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please post the HTML content as well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is likely that the first child node is a **text node** and not an element node. This is the case, for example, when your HTML looks like this:

```
<div>
    <div> I'm the first element child</div>
</div>
```

The line break after the first `div` and the spaces before the second one are one text node.

To get the element nodes, use [`children` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Element.children):

```
headDiv.children[0].innerHTML = "Working";
```

**Note:** IE6 - IE8 include comment nodes in `children` as well. As long as you have no comments there, it is fine.

---

Alternatively you can traverse the child nodes, looking for the first element node:

```
var child = element.firstChild;
while(child && child.nodeType !== 1) child = child.nextSibling;
```

**Reference:** [`Node.firstChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.firstChild), [`Node.nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nodeType), [`Node.nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.nextSibling).

---

**If** you want to change the value of a text node, you have to change the [`nodeValue` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nodeValue) property:

```
node.nodeValue = "Working";
```

Comment: Instead of Children i recomend getElementsByTagName, like `document.getElementById('sliderContainer').getElementsByTagName("div")[0]`